# How Do You Exclude Items From A Search Query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to go through a list of items, and exclude any items where the word "football" shows up. I did a search and found the term "exclude" but that just breaks my code. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
        ViewBag.FootballLeagues = _context.Leagues
            .Where(l => l.Sport.Exclude("Football"))
            .ToList();
        return View();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "exclude" you mean don't show the one with the specific value, you can do this:

```
    ViewBag.FootballLeagues = _context.Leagues
        .Where(l => l.Sport != "Football")
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot that perfectly answers my question and it works. I'll accept the answer you as soon as it lets me do it.

Comment: For case insensitive searches... `.Where(l => !l.Equals("FootBall", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: @quaabaam Assuming this is EF the query is going to be translated to SQL and case sensitivity is determined by the DB and depending on the version of EF that could result in an exception or worse it could end up running it client side.